# Two exception throws at the same time in ASP.Net MVC inside IIS, But can't see the exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC application into IIS(v8.5...) in windows server 2012 r2 standards server. It sets to windows authentication mode and in my browser it is throwing below exception,

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

So basically the one option is to get the errors is to add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in the `Web.config` file. So I did that, then it throws,

> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

It is the same thing I have done and it says again to do so. even same message appear if I change `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` mode.

I'm looking for a guidance to find a way to read that exception, that is not showing though custom error mode set to off.

Update -  Web config (Only system web part),

```
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
   <!-- <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/UnAuthorized" statusCode="401" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" statusCode="403" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/InternalServerError" statusCode="500" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotImplemented" statusCode="501" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/BadGateway" statusCode="502" />
    </customErrors>-->

    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="BmtRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="BmtRoleProvider" type="BMWebApplication.Models.Security.BmtRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: [Stackify Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/) is a great tool for getting more insight into what is going on in your web app. I have no affiliation to them (its free anyway).

Answer (score 0):

My first concern was to find out what exactly the error, since application return a false error and that error doesn't provide any clue.

Another way to see the exception throws by the application is to use Event Viewer and steps as below,

- Search for "Event Viewer" in your server.
- On your left, find "Windows Logs".
- Under the "Windows Logs" you can find "Application" and when you click that it will load content on your right.

From that log, you can find out the exact reason that prevents the application from starting. In my case browser doesn't show any error.